# Trying to setup elasticsearch cluster with docker-compose

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

My environment is two physical machine, both running in docker-compose.

I want to create elasticsearch cluster cross two docker container.

[My architecture like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw1so.png)

two container can't connected each other, any ideas?

docker image is using elasticsearch:5.4.2

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: es:542
    hostname: es2
    container_name: es2
    user: elasticsearch
    ports:
    - 9200:9200
    - 9300:9300
    environment:
    - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g
    command: /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
```

elasticsearch.yml

```
http.host: 0.0.0.0
transport.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2

cluster.name: prod_es_cluster
node.name: prod_es_node1
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping_timeout: 10s

network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: 0.0.0.0
transport.tcp.port: 9300
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
```

and logs

```
ES1
```

[2017-11-09T05:56:10,552][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService ] [prod_es_node1] publish_address `{172.24.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}`
[2017-11-09T05:56:10,558][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks ] [prod_es_node1] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address,enforcing bootstrap checks
[2017-11-09T05:56:40,576][WARN ][o.e.n.Node ][prod_es_node1]`timed out while waiting for initial discovery state - timeout: 30s`
[2017-11-09T05:56:40,584][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [prod_es_node1] publish_address `{172.24.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}`
[2017-11-09T05:56:40,587][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [prod_es_node1] started

```
ES2
```

[2017-11-09T09:37:20,084][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery ] [prod_es_node2]failed to connect to master [{prod_es_node1}{BxKzhOnJTUC50cYTz_Hm fA}{zqtU07jfQJOrmB9AYL01Ig}`{172.24.0.2}{172.24.0.2:9300}], retrying...`
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException:[prod_es_node1]`[172.24.0.2:9300] connect_timeout[30s]`
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.connectToChannels(Netty4Transport.java:361) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:549) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.connectToNode(TcpTransport.java:473) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:315) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:302) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.joinElectedMaster(ZenDiscovery.java:468) [elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.innerJoinCluster(ZenDiscovery.java:420) [elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.access$4100(ZenDiscovery.java:83) [elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$JoinThreadControl$1.run(ZenDiscovery.java:1197) [elasticsearch-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569) [elasticsearch-5.4.2.
jar:5.4.2]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException:`Connection refused: 172.24.0.2/172.24.0.2:9300`
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I use `openvswitch` and `pipework` to build cluster network

ovs setting:

```
#ES1
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo ip link set dev br0 up
sudo ovs-vsctl add-br ovs0
sudo ovs-vsctl set bridge ovs0 stp_enable=true
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port ovs0 br0
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port ovs0 gre0 -- set interface gre0 type=gre options:remote_ip=10.251.34.50
```

pipwork setting:

```
sudo pipework-master/pipework br0 -i eth1 es1 172.28.0.2/8
```

docker container network information:

elasticsearch@es1:/usr/share/elasticsearch$ ip a

521: eth1@if522:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4e:06:91:91:1f:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.28.0.2/8 brd 172.255.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

after setting both two docker container, cluster should be work !!

## ES1

```
elasticsearch@es1:/usr/share/elasticsearch$ ping 172.18.0.2
PING 172.18.0.2 (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.222 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.339 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.547 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.303 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.333 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.362 ms`
```

## ES logs:

```
[2017-11-17T02:06:21,205][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [prod_es_node1] started
[2017-11-17T02:06:21,223][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [prod_es_node1] new_master {prod_es_node1}{IoG7C5BYQ26AYsggMuJo2A}{AL3oD0itR1CgibIr-x-8Sg}{172.28.0.2}{172.28.0.2:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2017-11-17T02:06:21,254][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [prod_es_node1] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2017-11-17T02:06:29,205][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [prod_es_node1] added {{prod_es_node2}{ZA7CwKyBQS2gm-OamVSz2g}{U6WQyzwoQCiDkwBvmUxoQw}{172.18.0.2}{172.18.0.2:9300},}, reason: zen-disco-node-join[{prod_es_node2}{ZA7CwKyBQS2gm-OamVSz2g}{U6WQyzwoQCiDkwBvmUxoQw}{172.18.0.2}{172.18.0.2:9300}]`
```

## TEST

```
curl localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "prod_es_cluster",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```